# How to run scripts in the background while still being able to call alert functions

Tags: javascript, html, background, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

Hi I created a website to go to other websites within the website i made so as to bypass Device manager applications. It was mainly made for research so that people who need to go to websites blocked by the Device manager applications can access them through my website. I now need to control it so that it only works after school hours and during break time. The script is not able to run in the background and is only checked once. Below is the script for my code:

```
let d = new Date();
//alert(d);

let hrs = d.getHours();
let min = d.getMinutes();
let day = d.getDay();
//let auth = false
//const sec = d.getSeconds();
//alert(hrs);
//alert(min);
function pass() {
  return prompt("Enter Password:", "Unlocked during 10:40am to 11:20am GMT+0800 (Singapore Standard Time)");
}
function word() {
while (true) {
    if (pass() == "void") {
        //auth = true;
        break
    }else{
        alert("invalid password")
        
    }
}
}
function breaks() {
    if (hrs == 10 && min >= 40) {
        return true
    }else if (hrs == 11 && min < 20) {
        return true
    }else {
        return false
    }
}
if (hrs >= 14 || hrs < 8 || breaks() == true|| day == 0 || day == 6 /*|| auth == true*/){
    //alert("pass not needed");
    
}else {
    alert("You are using this website during school hours. Pls enter the password to bypass. Current time: " + d);
    word();
}
```

That is the script that needs to run in the background of this code (It's a PWA by the way) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<style>
body {
  background-color: #2C2F33;
}
</style>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Azlan's iframe Browser">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, no-store">
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
  <title> Iframe Browser </title>
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://azlancoding.github.io/iframe-browser-pwa/" />
  <link rel="manifest" href="/iframe-browser-pwa/manifest.webmanifest">
  <meta name="keywords" content="bypass, school, browser in website, cloud browser">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <title> iFrame browser </title>
  <script language="javascript">
    function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays){
        var exdate=new Date();exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
        var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
        document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
    }

    function getCookie(c_name){
        var c_value = document.cookie;
        var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
        if (c_start == -1){
            c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        }
        if (c_start == -1){
            c_value = null;
        }
        else{
            c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
            var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1){
                c_end = c_value.length;
            }
            c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
        }
        return c_value;
    }

    checkSession();

function checkSession(){
   var c = getCookie("visited");
   if (c === "yes") {
     alert("Welcome back! Make sure you have your extension on.");
   } 
    else {
    ext_install();
   }
}
function ext_install() 
    {
  if (window.confirm('An extension is required for this website to work. Do you want to install it now?')) 
   {    
        setCookie("visited", "yes", 365)
        window.location.href='https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ignore-x-frame-headers/gleekbfjekiniecknbkamfmkohkpodhe';
        };
  };

function checkCookie() {
  let user = getCookie("alerted");
  if (user != "") {
    alert("Welcome again !");
    } else 
    {ext_install();}
    
}
   //document.getElementById("myIframe").src = "https://wwf.org";
   var iframe = document.getElementById("myIframe");
   //var website = iframe.src;
   //console.log(website);
   document.addEventListener("scroll", function(event) 
   {
    var style = document.getElementById("myIframe").style;
    style.webkitTransform = style.webkitTransform ? "" : "scale(1)";
   })
   /*function resizeIframe()
   {
    document.getElementById('myIframe').height = 100%;
   }*/
   function ResetBox()
   {
   if(document.getElementById("URL").value == '')
   {document.getElementById("URL").value='Enter a URL here';};
   }
   function LoadPage()
   { 
     var objFrame=document.getElementById("myIframe"); 
     objFrame.src=document.getElementById("URL").value;
   }
   var elem = document.documentElement
   function openFullscreen() {
     if (elem.requestFullscreen) 
     {
        elem.requestFullscreen();
     }
     else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { 
        elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
     }
     else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { 
        elem.msRequestFullscreen();
     }
   }
   function closeFullscreen() {
     if (document.exitFullscreen) 
     {
        document.exitFullscreen();
     } 
     else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) 
     {
        document.webkitExitFullscreen();
     } 
     else if (document.msExitFullscreen) 
     {
       document.msExitFullscreen();
     }
   }
  </script>
  <style>
  .iframe-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    /* 16:9 aspect ratio */
    padding-top: 56.25%;
    position: relative;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#2C2F33">
<div style="Clear:both;"> 
 <input type="text" value="https://www.google.com" class="frmUrlVal" ID="URL"onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter a URL here') {this.value='https://'}" onblur="if (this.value == 'https://' || this.value == 'http://') { this.value='Enter a URL here';}">
 <input type="submit" class="frmSubmit" value="Go" onclick="LoadPage()">
 <input type="button" VALUE="&#65513"  onClick="history.back()"> 
 <input type="button" VALUE="&#65515"  onClick="history.forward()"> 
 <input type="button" class="fullscreen" value="&#x26F6;" onclick="openFullscreen()">
 <input type="button" class="Exitfullscreen" value="Exit Fullscreen" onclick="closeFullscreen()">
 <button class="newWindow" onclick=" window.open('https://azlancoding.github.io/iframe-browser-pwa/','_blank')">New Window</button>
 <button class="cloudbrowser" onclick=" window.open('https://replit.com/@azlancoding/free-and-unlimited-cloud-browser?embed=true','_blank')">Cloud browser</button>
</div>
<iframe align="center" width="100%" height="95%" src="https://www.google.com" onload = "check()" onerror"ext_install" allow="camera;microphone" frameborder=yes loading ="lazy" name="myIframe" id="myIframe"> </iframe>
<script>
function check(){
  document.getElementById("URL").value = "Enter a URL here";
}
</script>
  <script>
      if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register (
          '/iframe-browser-pwa/sw.js',
          {scope: '/iframe-browser-pwa/'}
        )
      }
  </script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My github project is https://github.com/AzlanCoding/iframe-browser-pwa

I tried using web workers but they can't show alert boxes.

Comment: Suddenly realised how long the post is...

Comment: Can't you have a [timer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) update the page periodically and toggle the app state depending on the setpoint hours?

Comment: Great idea, but how do I do that? I'm sorry but I'm new to javascript and html.

Comment: Do you need the date and time to constantly update every so often?

Comment: Every minute I guess

Comment: Well, in that case, you can create a function that updates the date and time every five or so minutes. You can use `setInterval` to run a function every so often. You can use it like this: `setInterval(updateFunction, 300000);` You need 300000 because 300 seconds is 5 minutes, and `setInterval` only accepts milliseconds.

Comment: ey no problemo !